# Values assignment in C++: runtime or compile time

Tags: c++, variables

I know that `constexpr` makes a constant which value is always created during a compile time. But what about plain variables? If I do it like `int x = 1`

is value being assigned to this variable during the compile time or the runtime?

Comment: Build it, and look at the generated assembly code. Check both unoptimized and optimized builds.

Comment: And a little nipicking: `int x = 1;` doesn't have an assignment, it's an *initialization* of `x`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule

Comment: You know that using `constexpr` is the way to make it compile-time. So if you just use  `int x = 1;` you obviously don't care. So why do you care what the compiler does when you told it you don't care?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to consider here is the as-if rule. For details I refer you to [What exactly is the "as-if" rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule). In a nutshell, it says that the program produced by the compiler must have the same observable beahvior as if it followed literally what you write in your code. Beyond that the compiler can do any optimizations it deems applicable.

`int x = 1;` has no observable behavior. If `x` is never used, then a compiler is free to not emit code that corresponds to this line that would be executed at runtime. If the compiler can see that `x` is never used, it also must not initialize some variable with `1` at compile time. You need to consider the context to understand compiler optimizations, because the compiler considers context when it applies optimizations.

However, `int x = 1;` here `x` is not a constant expression. Even if the compiler initializes `x` at compile time with `1`, `x` is not something you can use where a constant expression is required (size of arrays, template arguments, etc).